# Multiple inserts across tables with serial primary keys

Tags: postgresql

[I asked this question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010439/multiple-inserts-across-three-tables-capturing-a-serial-id-column-in-postgres), but I'm thinking it's better on this stack. Apologies if I've got that wrong. The motivation for this question is to prepare some sql scripts I can run during unit tests and production to define a bunch of master data for a web-based application that I'm building.

I have three tables, which I've abbreviated into the following

```
create table top (top_id serial, top_name text);
create table mid (mid_id serial, top_id integer, mid_name text);
create table bot (bot_id serial, mid_id integer, bot_name text);
```

what I want to achieve is

- insert a value into top, and capture it's ID
- insert multiple values into mid, using the same top_id,
- for each value in mid, insert multiple values into bot, using each mid_id.

So, the final result might look like

```
top
----
1, first_top
2, second_top

mid
---
1, 1, first_mid_for_first_top
2, 1, second_mid_for_first_top
3, 2, first_mid_for_second_top

bot
---
1, 1, first_bot_for_first_mid
2, 1, second_bot_for_first_mid
3, 3, first_bot_for_third_mid
```

My first approach was to try to have a bunch of nested CTEs, but I couldn't make that into valid syntax (and on consideration, I think that it's not the right approach).

My second approach was to try to store the values into some sort of variable, but I don't know how to do that outside of the pg command line tool.

What I'm after is something analogous to

```
top_id_one = insert into top(null, 'first_top') returning top_id
mid_id_one = insert into mid(null, top_id_one, 'first_mid_for_first_top) returning mid_id
insert into bot(null, mid_id_one, 'first_bot_for_first_mid')
```

in a "pure sql" that I could paste into PG admin for example.

I realise that there's a few problems in the example above (for example using 'top' as a table name). My explorations have avoided these issues, but I was trying to find table names that would make my example make sense.

Comment: `insert into top values (null, 'first_top')` will overwrite the default, and will store a `null` value in the `id` column. If you want the serial (sequence) to do it's job, you need to use `insert into top (top_name) values ('first_top')`

Answer (score 1):

The following is incorrect:

```
insert into top values (null, 'first_top')
```

You are explicitly passing `null` for the first column. Postgres **will** (try to) store that value in the column and the sequence (that the `serial` uses) will not be used! By supplying an explicit value for a `serial` column (or any column with a default) you are overwriting that automatic default.

---

Now for the actual question:

You can use `lastval()` to obtain the most recently generated sequence value:

```
insert into top (top_name) values ('first_top');
insert into mid (top_id, mid_name) values (lastval(), 'first_mid_for_first_top');
insert into bot (mid_id, bot_name) values (lastval(), 'first_bot_for_first_mid');
```

You can't however insert multiple rows into the `mid` table in a single statement with that.

Comment: you can use 'default' in place of 'null': `insert into top (top_id, top_name) values (default, 'first_top');`